# Find all connected groups of data (graphs) in a self joined table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion, hierarchical-data, circular-reference

Given a self joined many to many data set, with join table as below. How can I output the different graphs of connected data points with some kind of filter so that each cluster can be identified?

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Partner (MyID VARCHAR(1), PartnerID VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('A', 'B')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('B', 'A')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('A', 'C')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('C', 'A')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('C', 'D')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('D', 'C')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('A', 'D')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('D', 'A')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('X', 'Y')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('Y', 'X')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('Z', 'X')
INSERT INTO Partner VALUES ('X', 'Z')
```

[Diagram of record connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4itS.jpg)

Such as the linked image shows, I desire to have A-B-C-D as one group with ID and X-Y-Z with another group ID. All so that I can ultimately use this query to create a view.

Ideal Result:

```
MyID PartnerID GroupID
A     B         1
B     A         1
A     C         1
C     A         1
C     D         1
D     C         1
A     D         1
D     A         1
X     Y         2
Y     X         2
Z     X         2
X     Z         2
```

I have done a little research and have found similar problems that use a CTE with recursion to returns groups of related nodes. However, nothing that I have found works with my particular data set. The issue seems to be with the circular nature of my data references causing either a max recursion limit error or being filtered out. A similar example that fails with my data is: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost520864.aspx

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one? It seems like I could be missing something simple, but the idea of recursive CTEs is already a new and confusing concept to me.

Edit: Maybe simplfying the problem 2-4 nodes is the limit of nodes expected in this system. Anything more, is invalid and I aim to prevent those entries.

Comment: Considering getting users to manually enter this group relation as a work around. Sadly still no luck finding an elegant solution. I'll share if one comes up.

Comment: A view created from a TVF such as this might be the solution. Only difference is they avoid the reference back such as A->B and B->A https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/t-sql-puzzle-challenge-grouping-connected-items

Comment: Billy, the fourth option from that link looks like a good option. Do you have any data in your system where you would have B-A but not A-B?  If not, then I would process the data using the fourth method from the link you gave, but using only data from your system where the lowest ID is first (Ie, A-B, not B-A). Once you have done that processing, you can join the results back to your original data in Col1=Col2 & Col2=Col1 to get your final expected result.