# Regrouping groups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to solve the below problem, I have an existing dataset that is already grouped, but I need to it to be grouped further based on the common "SO_Number" in the dataset, example below:

**Current Data:**

| Group_Key | SO_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 233738 | SO21268046 |
| 233738 | **SO21269767** |
| 234129 | **SO21269767** |
| 234129 | SO21274404 |
| 234129 | SO21271542 |
| 234129 | **SO21274421** |
| 234421 | **SO21274421** |
| 234421 | SO21276633 |
| 234421 | **SO21276877** |
| 88964 | **SO21276877** |
| 88964 | SO21278203 |
| 88964 | SO21278329 |
| 234727 | SO21278329 |
| 234727 | SO21279199 |
| 234727 | **SO21279542** |
| 91016 | **SO21279542** |
| 91016 | SO21289940 |
| 88111 | SO21289664 |
| 88111 | **SO21289665** |
| 88112 | **SO21289665** |
| 88112 | SO21289677 |
| 88113 | SO21289678 |

**Expected Data output:**

| NewGroup_Key | Group_key | SO_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 233738 | SO21268046 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 233738 | SO21269767 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234129 | SO21269767 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234129 | SO21274404 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234129 | SO21271542 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234129 | SO21274421 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234421 | SO21274421 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234421 | SO21276633 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234421 | SO21276877 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 88964 | SO21276877 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 88964 | SO21278203 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 88964 | SO21278329 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234727 | SO21278329 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234727 | SO21279199 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 234727 | SO21279542 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 91016 | SO21279542 |
| 233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016 | 91016 | SO21289940 |
| 88111,88112 | 88111 | SO21289665 |
| 88111,88112 | 88112 | SO21289677 |
| 88113 | 88113 | SO21289678 |

The expected data output I need should be in three groups instead of nine groups as they're all grouped by SO_Number - hence creating a new group key (NewGroup_Key) that will be used for new mapping of the data. Note that this is just a subset of the dataset so there are other groups that are involved as well. I have bolded the SO_number where each of the groups should be linked(grouped) in the "Current Data" table.

I have tried a few queries my end but didn't lead to anything reasonable or easy to follow using SQL. So any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Please do not post image. Post your sample data and expected as formatted text. Please also include your attempted query and explain the necessary logic required

Comment: @Squirrel, thanks for your comment, have added in the sample data and the expected outcome. Query wise, I attempted it, but doesn't provide anything solid or anything able to follow, let me know if you need more details

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the results, please explain

Comment: @Charlieface, In the "Current Data" - each group is represented by a "Group_Key" - each group will have multiple "SO_Number". The end result has a new column: "NewGroup_Key" which is a concatation of all the "Group_Key" in the "Current Data". The reason for this is that all the groups are linked by "SO_Number" that are bolded in the "Current Data". For example: Group_key - 233738 and 234129 are linked by the SO_Number - SO21269767 and similar logic to the other groups as well. Hence, all the groups above are "Linked" hence resulting in a big group for this example.

Comment: But take for example the first row `233738,234129,234421,88964,234727,91016` why is `234421` in there? It sounds almost like you want to group everything using graphing, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741419/find-all-connected-groups-of-data-graphs-in-a-self-joined-table

Answer (score 0):

Hen you say 'clustering' are you referring to this?

```
declare @t TABLE (
   category int  NOT NULL 
  ,segment  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,payment  int  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'A',1425);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'B',7647);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'A',6164);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'B',3241);

--if you want payment column as string then use following

SELECT
category, 
segment,
    STRING_AGG(cast(payment as nvarchar(50)),'+') payment
FROM
   @t T
GROUP BY
    category,segment
```

Result:

[image]